# Creating a 2-page Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

Those big boxes at the top are just there to cover up customer info

I have to design reports for custom pack slips for a couple of customers. Putting their logo on the report and their special footer is no problem.

Where things get hairy is that they both have a whole other page worth of stuff like policy information, return info, this and that, that they want printed as part of their pack slip.

I'm pretty new to Crystal Reports, but I'm kind of sure you can't just... do that. I thought "oh I'll just stuff this in the Page Footer section and select "New Page Before" and it'll just print on the next page!" ... no. No, that is not how that works, apparently.

So, is it even possible to create a report that has two pages or am I going to just have to set up the script to print two different documents for them?

Comment: What is the layout of your report? Is there grouping, are you displaying the Details section with a variable number of records, etc.? You'll have better luck putting that stuff in the Report Footer than the Page Footer, since the Page Footer really is intended to be a part of each individual page and CR might do some weird stuff if you try to force a page break.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the layout is... um... There's the Page Header, Group Header #1 (suppressed), Group Header #2 (suppressed), Details, Group Footer #2 (suppressed), Group Footer #1, and Page Footer. I tried putting the information they wanted in the Report Footer, but then I got an error from our warehouse application saying the report couldn't fit the page.

Comment: Yep, that's the layout. What do you mean by "got an error from our warehouse application"? Is this report a part of some custom software as opposed to a standalone report? CR itself shouldn't care how many pages the report is, is why I ask.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain how it works because I can't dig into it. All I know is I've modified this report we use for packslips to put some other company's logo and information on it, and when they try to generate the packslip, it gives them an error saying something about the report not fitting on one page. I don't think it's something Crystal Reports is doing, it has something to do with the application we use.

Comment: that error comes up when page header + page footer are greater than the page size setup in your printer, could you port a picture of how your current report looks in design view?

Comment: I will but, it's kind of huge!

Comment: How unique is the policy & return information. Is that also dependent on each company? We used a print shop to pre-print policy terms on the backside and unique packing slip details on the blank side.

Comment: The policy and return information is unique to that company, which is why we needed to produce a customized packslip. Generally we just use the generic packslip report, but some of our customers need them printed on packslips that look like theirs. The idea of printing things on the back-side of the report sounds great though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. It just took a little creative re-design of the report.

I moved all of the stuff in "Page Header" to "Report Header". That way I wouldn't get all of the shipping information and what not printed on every page.

then I moved all of the detail headers from "Page Header" to "Group Header #1" and completely suppressed the Page Header section.

Then I moved all that huge mess to the Report Footer section, right-clicked on "Report Footer" and went in to the Section Expert and checked "New Page Before".

Voila, it comes out exactly the way I want it to. It just took a little bit of learning and understanding exactly how these reports go together and what the sections do and how they work. I might not have mentioned this, but I have NEVER touched CR before this project was put on my desk.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: The only issue I can imagine occurring with this solution is that if  the number of items ordered exceeds the page size, the detail headers will not be reprinted on the next page, I dont' think, since I moved them to Group Header #1... Does anyone know if Crystal Reports prints Group Headers on each page, or just once at the top of the group?

Answer (score 0):

To print the group header on each page:
- choose Group expert from report menu
- Select the group then click on "Options..."
- select Options tab
- check "Repeat group header on each page" box